# The field was declared on serializer , but has not been included error in django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created few serializers in my django REST API and stuck with weird problem. When i go to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register/` url i'm gets the error:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/users/
>
> Django Version: 1.10.2 Python Version: 3.5.2 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'rest_framework',  'api'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _legacy_get_response
>     249.             response = self._get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     215.                 response = response.render()
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in render
>     109.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     72.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py"
>   in render
>     697.         context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py"
>   in get_context
>     630.         raw_data_post_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'POST', request)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py"
>   in get_raw_data_form
>     553.                 content = renderer.render(serializer.data, accepted, context)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py"
>   in data
>     508.         ret = super(Serializer, self).data
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py"
>   in data
>     244.                 self._data = self.get_initial()
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py"
>   in get_initial
>     387.             for field in self.fields.values()
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py"
>   in fields
>     340.             for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py"
>   in get_fields
>     947.         field_names = self.get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
>
> File
>   "D:\code\active\Python\Django\photo-hub\photo-hub\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py"
>   in get_field_names
>     1046.                         serializer_class=self.**class**.**name**
>
> Exception Type: AssertionError at /api/users/ Exception Value: The
>   field 'photos' was declared on serializer UserSerializer, but has not
>   been included in the 'fields' option.

But my UserSerializer doesn't even have 'photos' field. I'm new in django, please, help me to understand source of this problem.

serializers.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import serializers

from api.models import Album, Photo

class PhotoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="photo-detail")
    album = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='album-detail', queryset=Album.objects)
    owner = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', queryset=User.objects)

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'image', 'creation_date', 'owner', 'album')
        read_only_fields=('creation_date')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="album-detail")
    owner = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='user-detail', queryset=User.objects)
    photos = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='photo-list',  queryset=Photo.objects, many=True)

    def get_validation_exclusions(self):
        # Need to exclude `author` since we'll add that later based off the request
        exclusions = super(AlbumSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + ['user']

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('pk', 'name', 'creation_date', 'owner', 'photos')
        read_only_fields=('creation_date')

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="user-detail", read_only=True)
    albums = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='album-list', queryset=Album.objects)

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'pk', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'is_staff', 'albums')
        write_only_fields = ('password')
        read_only_fiels = ('pk')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user    


    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password']:
            if data['password'] != data['confirm_password']:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "The passwords have to be the same"
                )
        return data
```

AuthRegister view

```
class AuthRegister(APIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import AuthRegister
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'albums', views.AlbumViewSet)
router.register(r'photos', views.PhotoViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^login/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
    url(r'^register/$', AuthRegister.as_view()),
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback ?

Comment: Add full traceback.

Comment: I'm not familiar with REST framework, but my suspicion would be this is something to do with the photos field from your album resource being propogated into your user one.

Comment: Can't really spot something wrong here. Try removing some serializer to see if changes something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally i found source of my stupid error. Reason was that earlier i had photo field in my model. But after making changes in model i forget to make migrations.